# Siemens TIA OPENNESS V15.1 demo

Tags: c#, siemens

I am trying to learn the TIA openness example V15.1 demo from here

https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/108716692/tia-portal-openness-introduction-and-demo-application?dti=0&lc=en-WW

But when I click the .exe file, I only got the assembly selection window, nothing else. What is wrong? I am using the Tia portal V16 version.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce this error with a system having V16 installed, nor with a system having both V15.1 and V16 installed.

The window shown above is not a component of the demo application.  It is generated by TIA Portal itself.

There may be something wrong with your installation.  Perhaps you are the same person as has posted here, if yes - please comment on this answer saying that your solution was resolved:
https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/ww/en/posts/urgent-tia-openness-v15-demo/267153?page=0&pageSize=300

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the application shows an Assembly Selection dialog for you to choose which TIA version. After choosing compatible TIA and Openness versions. You click OKAY, then the application shows the Demo Main Windows.

If it not works, open Solution in VS and Debug.

Comment: The application does not show the Assembly Selection dialog - TIA Portal does, and it seems to appear when there is a corrupt Openness installation.  Did you test this, or are you guessing how it works?